# What trait isn't implemented?

Tags: rust, traits, actix-web

Novice Rustacean here ... coded up an example and found it required version 1.0.8 of actix.  That worked fine. Then decided to upgrade it to the latest 4.3.0 and kablooey!

I've been staring at it for over an hour.  Here's the code and error message.  Any hints?

```rust
    fn main() {
    let server = HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            //.route("/", web::get().to(get_index))     // for actix-web = "1.0.8"
            //.route("/gcd", web::post().to(post_gcd))  // for actix-web = "1.0.8"
            .service(web::resource("/").route(web::get().to(get_index)))     // line  9
            .service(web::resource("/gcd").route(web::post().to(post_gcd)))  // line 10
    });

    println!("Serving on http://locaohost:3000 ...");
    server
        .bind("127.0.0.1:3000").expect("error binding server to address.")
        .run().expect("error running server");
}

fn get_index() -> HttpResponse {
    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("text/html")
        .body(
            r#"
                <title>GCD Calculator</title>
                <form action="/gcd" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="n"/>
                <input type="text" name="m"/>
                <button type="submit">Compute GCD</button>
                </form>
            "#,
        )
}
. . .
```

! The trait bound `fn() -> HttpResponse {get_index}: Handler<_>` is not satisfied.

! The trait bound `fn(Form<GcdParameters>) -> HttpResponse {post_gcd}: Handler<_>` is not satisfied.

! No method named `expect` found for struct `Server` in the current scope.

Comment: [What is a Request Handler](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/trait.Handler.html#what-is-a-request-handler)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75544059/trait-bound-in-actix-routes. I think your problem is the same problem discussed in the linked question, namely your routes must be `async` functions (or functions that return a type that implements `Future`).